# What is the best method for hiding a div onclick and storing a cookie?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, hide

I see many websites today displaying information in divs that a user can choose to hide with onClick.

I'm assuming that upon click they set a cookie in the users browser that stops the message from  showing again (at least whilst the cookie is set).

I would like to know what the quickest, most efficient way of doing this is. I haven't included the jquery framework on my site and am undecided in whether I need it or not.

Is jQuery the best approach or is there a more lightweight way of doing it? Does jQuery majorly effect page speeds??

Comment: If you where going to use juqery just to toggle a elements display/visibility, and set a cookie i would say no

Comment: thanks David, I will be using jQuery me thinks.

Comment: @david depends how many times the OP types `document.getElementById('');` - jQuery is `$('');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already been answered here -> [jQuery Toggle Cookie Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982233/jquery-toggle-cookie-support)

I use jQuery on all my web development projects - its easy of use and small amount of code (required to be written) far out weighs any disadvantages (not that i can think of any!!)

You dont even have to host jQuery if you dont want to - let someone else (google) host it for you ... this article is a couple of years (2008) old but still VERY relevant -> http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) may not be the best thing, but it's the quickest for this I think. It has some nice Ajax functions, you could call to set cookies with PHP for example.

Answer (score 1):

That depends a lot on

- How likely are you to make use of other jQuery library features such as selectors, ajax, animation etc ?
- Are you willing to sacrifice time dealing with cross browser issues writing your own javascript to get and set the cookies ? With jQuery you could use a plugin which makes it a little easier to deal with.

If you do decide to go with jQuery then your visitors browser will cache the external javascript files for subsequent requests so subsequent page load times are mitigated.