# Hide/show a block permanently

Tags: jquery, toggle

I am using slidetoggle to open and close div, with easing using jquery.

```
<script>
 function toggleText() {
 $('#divToToggle').slideToggle("slow");
 if ($('#divToToggle').css('display') == 'none') {
      $('#aTag').html('Show');
 }
 else {
      $('#aTag').html('Hide');
 }
 }
</script>
<a id="aTag" href="javascript:toggleText();">
  Hide
</a>
```

The div it controls is `<div id="divToToggle"></div>`

Issue I have is onclick the text isnt changing , from Show to Hide and vice versa... I must be missing something very very simple..

Bugger also meant to ask, how do i attah a cookie to the event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this . This will work

```
<script>
     function toggleText() {
          $('#divToToggle').slideToggle("slow", function(){
             if ($('#divToToggle').css('display') == 'none') {
                 $('#aTag').html('Show');
             }
             else 
             {
                 $('#aTag').html('Hide');
             }    
       });    
     }
</script>
<a id="aTag" href="javascript:toggleText();">
      Hide
</a>
```

**EDIT :**
Here is a simple function on how to set and delete a cookie - [src](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2010/09/jquery-cookies-getsetdelete-plugin.html) -

```
  function setCookie(name,value,days) {
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
            var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
        }
        else var expires = "";
        document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
    }

    function getCookie(name) {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
        }
        return null;
    }

    function deleteCookie(name) {
        setCookie(name,"",-1);
    }

   function toggleText() {
              $('#divToToggle').slideToggle("slow", function(){
                 if ($('#divToToggle').css('display') == 'none') {
                     $('#aTag').html('Show');
                      deleteCookie('hiddendiv') 

                 }
                 else 
                 {
                     $('#aTag').html('Hide');
                     setCookie('hiddendiv',1,MENTOINYOURTIMEHERE)  
                 }    
           });    
         }

  $('aTag').click('toggleText');
  if(getCookie('hiddendiv'))
  {
    $('#divToToggle').hide();
  }

<a id="aTag" href="javascript:toggleText();">
      Hide
</a>
<div id ="divToToggle"></div>
```

Comment: Thankyou , just cookie issue now

Comment: you mean you wish to set and delete a cookie

Comment: hi @Web Developer if user hides the div, then on refresh need to remember the div state, using cookie. So it isnt opened everytime they open / close div. Nearest I found is: but i dont understand it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982233/jquery-toggle-cookie-support

Comment: @422 i have done the very same thing but dont have the code now. Let me try to write one for you

Comment: Thanks , I am really crap at this lol. Appreciate your help :)

Comment: No one is a crap. Look at my answer but as @Mahbub suggests use jquery cookie instead

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5749/discussion-between-web-developer-and-422)

Answer (score 1):

Live on JSFiffle http://jsfiddle.net/T7vFf/

```
<script>
function toggleText() {
    $('#divToToggle').slideToggle("300", function() {
        if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
            $('#aTag').html('Hide');
        } else {
            $('#aTag').html('Show');
        }
    });
}
</script>

<a id="aTag" href="javascript:toggleText();">
  Hide
</a>
<div id="divToToggle">Div To Toggle</div>
```

Comment: Any idea how to attach cookie ?

Comment: Use the jQuery cookie plugin. http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/
Set the cookie everytime the div is hidden or shown and Check the cookie value on $(document).ready(..) and then modify the toggleText slightly to make divToToggle visible or hidden.

Comment: Thanks @Mahbub albeit i do front end, i dont do javascript etc.. I can just about get by. Thanks, will have a looksy